# Rewrite rule same for http and https apache .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

we bought some software from a third party provider and proceeded to install an ssl certificate...  When we go to the http version of the site, everything works fine, but when we go to https, the browser puts two slashes on the end of the root url, and redirects back to the http site...  I have no idea how to read rewrite rules, but we want the site to do the exact same thing whether it's http or https...  is there an easy way to update this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /handler.php
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /code
RewriteRule manage_articles\.php  /code/load_module.php?module_name=articles&file=manage_articles&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule manage_articles_cat_frame\.php  /code/load_module.php?module_name=articles&file=manage_articles_cat_frame&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule manage_articles_categories\.php  /code/load_module.php?module_name=articles&file=manage_articles_categories&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule modify_article\.php  /code/load_module.php?module_name=articles&file=modify_article&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule modify_article_cat\.php  /code/load_module.php?module_name=articles&file=modify_article_cat&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule manage_letters\.php  /code/load_module.php?module_name=letters&file=manage_letters&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule modify_letters\.php  /code/load_module.php?module_name=letters&file=modify_letters&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\.html$ article.php?path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\.htm$ article.php?cat_path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(article_[^\.]+\.gif)$ modules/articles/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^auctions\/([^\/]+)\/*$ auction.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^auctions\/([^\/]+)\/buy_now$ buy_product.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)(gif|jpg|css|png|js)$
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]



# api rewrite logic
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^services\/(.*)$ services/api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^services\/(.*)$ services/api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^services\/(.*)$ services/api.php [QSA,NC,L]
#end api rewrite
```

Again, I want the site to function EXACTLY the same, just handle https as well.

Thanks.

Adding vhosts.conf:

```
# linkz.com ssl
<VirtualHost 164.175.65.135:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/publicbz.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/private_nopp_bz.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
ServerAdmin webmaster@linkz.com
DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/micro
<Directory "/usr/local/www/micro">
AllowOverride All
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
ServerName www.linkz.com
ServerAlias linkz.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/linkz.error.log
#       CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 164.175.65.135:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/publicbz.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/private_nopp_bz.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
ServerAdmin webmaster@linkz.com
DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/microdev
<Directory "/usr/local/www/microdev">
AllowOverride All
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
ServerName dev.linkz.com
ServerAlias dev.linkz.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/linkzdev.error.log
#       CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# linkz.com
<VirtualHost 164.175.65.135:80>
#       ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/micro
<Directory "/usr/local/www/micro">
AllowOverride All
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
ServerName www.linkz.com
ServerAlias linkz.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/linkz.error.log
#       CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 164.175.65.135:80>
#       ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/microdev
<Directory "/usr/local/www/microdev">
AllowOverride All
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
ServerName dev.linkz.com
ServerAlias dev.linkz.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/linkzdev.error.log
#       CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Adding index.php:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']==443 && ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'www.auction.test' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'www.default.loc'))
{
header('Location: '.$GLOBALS['SERVER_PATH'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit;
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything in this code which would cause your described behaviour. Can you post both virtualhost definitions (:80 and :443) please?

Comment: Added vhosts.conf per Seybsen

Comment: Are you *sure* your php scripts aren't doing this?

Comment: added index.php...  this might be it.

Comment: it was the redirect in the index.php file...  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was the index.php file...  The issue was I got stuck on the rewrite rules and didn't think to look at the php files.